# Update link in GridView

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, c-sharp

I have written the below code for updating gridview, It's not working.

```
protected void Update_row(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
  //TextBox ID = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("txtID");
  TextBox Title = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
  TextBox Name = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");


                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
                {
                    UpdateRow(ID.Text, Title.Text, Name.Text);
                    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
                    Bind_Data();
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = ex.ToString();
            }

        }
```

After debugging I found that the ID, Title and Name values are **null**.

**Updated**

I found that I did not write the gridview code perfectly, so I made some changes there.

Now I am getting the values in those controls but these values are the already existing value, updated entries are not coming there.

```
Label ID = (Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("lblId");
                TextBox Name = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtName");
                TextBox Title = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txtTitle");
```

these are just getting the already existing values.

Comment: Why u commented that ID TextBox?

Comment: Actually, it's not commented...But still it takes null

Comment: i got it.. It was the ispostback event that needed to be used.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**

```
 GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];         
    TextBox ID = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtID");
    TextBox Title = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox1");
    TextBox Name = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox2");
```